# How to add a column in pandas with values by calling a function with argument from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, erpnext

I have a DataFrame with supplier codes.

| supplier_code |
| --- |
| V1001 |
| V1002 |
| V1003 |

I want to add a new column "Supplier Balance" by passing a function with "Supplier Code" as argument.

The function is

```
get_balance_on(party_type="Supplier",   party="V1001")
```

The above function returns the suppliers balance.

I tried this, but gives me an error related to index.

```
df["balance"] = get_balance_on(party_type="Supplier",   party=df["supplier_code"])
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It looks like you need to [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) the function to the series, or iterate the values and call the function on each element

Comment: @G.Anderson Thanks for the welcome and your quick response. I am a newbie to coding. Just figuring my way through. Your tip was of great help. I added the below line and it worked :). 

`df["balance"] = df.apply(lambda x: get_balance_on(party_type="Supplier",party=x['party']), axis=1)`

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Cheers, happy to assist and well done figuring out the answer from a hint.